# ember.js: using routes, templates and outlets to render model data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm going round in circles here, trying to pull all the components together to produce the desired view. I feel as if I just need to just tweak the dial to bring it all into focus but at the moment it aludes me.

I have two models - Person and Address - which I have created two templates for; I then want to render these two templates in another 'main' template. At the moment I am not linking them in anyway (eventually 1 person will have many nested addresses) because I want to understand the general principes first.

The two templates work individually using App.Router.map

```
this.resource('listOfPeopleTemplate', { path: '/' });
```

or

```
this.resource('listOfAddressesTemplate', { path: '/' });
```

but not together or when I add the mainViewTemplate and try to add both into that:

```
App.Router.map(function () {


  //this.resource('listOfAddressesTemplate', { path: '/' });
  //this.resource('listOfPeopleTemplate', { path: '/' });
  this.resource('mainViewTemplate', { path: '/' });
 });
```

The problem seems centered around:

```
App.MainViewTemplateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({   
    renderTemplate: function() {    
        this.render('listOfPeopleTemplate', {into: 'mainViewTemplate', outlet: 'peops'});
        this.render('listOfAddressesTemplate', {into: 'mainViewTemplate', outlet: 'address'});
    }  
});
```

Errors returned are "outlet (people) was specified but not found"; and "The value that #each loops over must be an Array..". I can see that I may need to do something about the controller for both the Addresses and People but I don't know what. Fact is, i've got myself into such a muddle I now can't even get the originally successfull version working (with either the address or people displaying in their own template).

I have made the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4gQYs/4/. Please, bring me into focus!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem!

I have two routes **people** and **places**.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('people');
    this.resource('places');

});
```

I am loading the model for both the controller in model hook of people route.

```
App.PeopleRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        var places=Em.A();
        $.getJSON("js/places.js").then(function(json){places.setObjects(json)});

        var placesController=this.generateController('places',places);
        placesController.set('content',places);

        var people=Em.A();
        $.getJSON("js/people.js").then(function(json){people.setObjects(json)});
        return people;
    },

    renderTemplate:function(){
        this.render('people',{into:"application",outlet:"people"});
        this.render('places',{into:"application",outlet:"places"});
    }
});
```

The following is not needed.May be useful in displaying some related data.

```
App.PeopleController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs:'places'
});
```

Now I am rendering the two templates in main application template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet people}}
    {{outlet places}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people">

    {{#each controller}}
        <p>{{name}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="places">

    {{#each controller}}
        <p>{{name}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm still not having any joy, though. I've converted my code using yours as reference to produce this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXJc5/11/). The only thing different is that i'm using Ember data model rather than an ember array. The result is I get a blank view back but no errors. Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: aha...that works, thank you. Can you tell me whether I understand the logic? Ember loads the application and first looks for the IndexRoute (although I thought it was the ApplicationRoute..or does it look for both?). The `redirect:function()this.transitionTo('people');}` tells ember to switch to the people route; where it loads the two models and renders using the two templates into the application (default) template. The other thing that I'm uncomfortable with is loading places via the peopleRoute by setting the PlaceController: it seems a little patchwork, don't you think?